# android resize image

Tags: android

I have added image in android, but it is fitting to middle of the screen, what can I do to set it for full screen?

what is wrap_content and fill parent, I'm not getting how to do this.

This is my code

```
<ImageView   
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:src="@drawable/my_image" android:cropToPadding="false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="center"
```

wrap_content says ImageView to fit image dimension and fill_parent to fit dimension of father layout.

Comment: How can i set the image to a particular x and y coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Look for scaleType

```
<ImageView android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Comment: Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html
Maybe you need android:scaleType="fitXY"
Try everything mentioned in the reference and you should be able to find what you need

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Read more about [ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).